# Share List URLs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How i can share List in flutter.

I use library flutter_share: ^2.0.0 but there I can send either a single text or a list of files, can I send a list of links as a set of files?

Comment: Didn't get you. Do you want to share a list of links as a text?

Comment: Yes, but each link must be separate

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) only shares texts so if you need to share a list join all links separated from `\n`

Comment: Flutter share can fumble files and there I can select a list of files and they will be sent as two files. (maybe you can somehow convert files to url) if not, can you advise another library that can do this?